# 'If' statement with multiple conditions over multiple lines in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am checking the existence of two files and after that setting a condition but I am getting an error message that the syntax is incorrect when I add the AND

```
If (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CStr(Dts.Variables("VNetworkFolderName").Value), "Z_Attendance.xls").Length > 0
and System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CStr(Dts.Variables("VNetworkFolderName").Value), "Z_EP.xls").Length > 0) Then
  Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value = True
Else
  Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value = False
End If
```

But if I check just one file without using AND statement, it works fine.

Comment: Have you added a line break before the `and` because the syntax is fine?

Comment: Thanks Obsedian, yes but still not working. However, when I remove the second condition AND, it work fine. If (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CStr(Dts.Variables("VNetworkFolderName").Value), "Z_Attendance.xls").Length > 0) Then
  Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value = True
Else
  Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value = False
End If

Comment: [How to: Break and Combine Statements in Code (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code)

Comment: You also might want to look at IO.File.Exists for checking for the existance of files : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_File_Exists_System_String_

Comment: You should also tick the answer that solved the problem for you. Like my answer lol :) Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, are you familiar with accepting answers? You've just asked a new question, and someone has pinged you here to remind. There's [plenty of resources on the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+accept+an+answer+at+stack+overflow) about this.

Answer (score 3):

Add an underscore `_` before the line terminates to indicate a line break.

```
If (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CStr(Dts.Variables("VNetworkFolderName").Value), "Z_Attendance.xls").Length > 0 _
And System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CStr(Dts.Variables("VNetworkFolderName").Value), "Z_EP.xls").Length > 0) Then
  Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value = True
Else
  Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value = False
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either put the line break after the 'And' or use a line continuation character (underscore). Also, it's usually better to use 'AndAlso' in modern VB.

```
If condition _
    AndAlso otherCondition Then
    DoThing()
Else
    DoOtherThing()
End If
```

Or

```
 If condition AndAlso 
    otherCondition Then
    DoThing()
Else
    DoOtherThing()
End If
```

Comment: @Obsidian That is not the case, the second won't be evaluated only if the first is false.

Comment: @Obsidian I think you are misunderstanding how short-circuiting works, here is the documentation for AndAlso : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version, the "And" should be on the first line with a _ at the end.

```
If (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CStr(Dts.Variables("VNetworkFolderName").Value), "Z_Attendance.xls").Length > 0 And _
    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CStr(Dts.Variables("VNetworkFolderName").Value), "Z_EP.xls").Length > 0) Then
  Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value = True
Else
  Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value = False
End If
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you everyone, problem is solved. Such a wonderful community, good day everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `GetFiles` twice is a bad idea.  It will iterate through all the folders in the directory twice!  You would be better off using `File.Exists` instead:

```
Dim folderName As String = CStr(Dts.Variables("VNetworkFolderName").Value
Dim filename1 = Path.Combine(folderName, "Z_Attendance.xls")
Dim filename2 = Path.Combine(folderName, "Z_EP.xls")

Dts.Variables("VCountAPAListFile").Value =  File.Exists(filename1) AndAlso File.Exists(filename2)
```